# Installing older version of GCC from source

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-12.04

I have gcc4.6 installed. I need 4.2 to be installed without disturbing current version. 
OS - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Either install using `--prefix` configure switch to choose another path to install to, or `--program-suffix` switch, e.g. `--program--suffix=-4.2`. [The docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) have more information.

Please note that by default, the prefix will be `/usr/local/`, but the Ubuntu package will install to just `/usr/`, so things should be fine. However, if your `$PATH` lists `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, you might still run into problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that straight-forward because the Ubuntu multiarch stuff will make 4.2 barf. :-(

Comment: I have tried both your options.
I don't have root access. Can I install in my home directory, instead  of '/usr/bin'?

Comment: Sure, see `--prefix`.

Comment: *** [crtbegin.o] Error 1

Comment: And that is supposed to tell me what? That your build failed? The comment section isn't really the appropriate place to ask such things...